What happens on the GPU during VkImage layout transition?
Is it possible for the driver (GPU) to shuffle pixels of a VkImage during layout transition ? Such as transitioning from linear ordering of pixels to a morton order ? I was unable to find any clear answers on the internet.
And more generally what happens on the GPU during image layout transition ? I know this is highly vendor dependent, but maybe it is possible to tell in general which kind of things may happen during that time.
And another loosely related question. Is it possible to transition an image created with VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL to VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL and read from it on CPU ?

Image layouts are entirely implementation-specific. Some layout transitions on some hardware are no-ops. Some hardware does layout transitions automatically based on need. Etc.
Layout transition can be expensive, so you should only do them where necessary. That's really the main point.

Is it possible to transition an image created with VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL to VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL and read from it on CPU ?

Layouts and tiling are completely orthogonal. Tiling is immutable; you set the tiling at image creation time and that is that image's tiling, forever. Layouts vary based on transitions.
If you use TILING_OPTIMAL on an image, then the CPU cannot read the data directly. Period.

So is it possible for a driver to change the ordering of pixels during layout transition ? Or what kind of things might the driver/GPU be doing to make the access to pixels of a texture more optimal ?

And regarding the tiling, if CPU can never read from tiled image, does it ever make sense to deliberately allocate a VkImage in memory that can be mapped on host ?
Given that there is no way for the CPU to access pixels of a tiled image directly (without copying them to a buffer or a linear image first) it seems to me that it makes no sense.

@jcxz: "does it ever make sense to deliberately allocate a VkImage in memory that can be mapped on host ?" Not every VkImage uses optimal tiling. Besides, there's no need to have the API explicitly forbid some combination of functionality just because it isn't useful.
